# Sorting a hash in ruby based on value and then key

Tags: ruby, sorting

How do you sort a hash in ruby based on the value and then key? For example

```
h = {4 => 5, 2 => 5, 7 => 1}
```

would sort into

```
[[7, 1], [2,5], [4, 5]]
```

I can sort based on the value by doing

```
h.sort {|x,y| x[1] <=> y[1]}
```

but I can't figure out how to sort based on value and then key if the values are the same

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
h.sort_by {|k, v| [v, k] }
```

This uses the fact that `Array` mixes in `Comparable` and defines `<=>` element-wise.

Note that the above is equivalent to

```
h.sort_by {|el| el.reverse }
```

which is equivalent to

```
h.sort_by(&:reverse)
```

which may or may not be more readable.

If you *know* that `Hash`es usually sort by key first, then by value, the above should be obvious. Maybe with a small comment:

```
h.sort_by(&:reverse) # sort by value first, then by key
```

---

Note: if you simply want to delegate to some property's `<=>` method, (i.e. sort by a key rather than a general comparison function) it is generally prefered to use `sort_by` instead of `sort`. It's much easier to read. Generally, it also happens to be faster, but the readability aspect is the more important one.

You should really only write your own comparison function if *absolutely* necessary.

So, your non-working example would better be written as

```
h.sort_by {|el| el[1] }
```

Personally, I prefer to use destructuring bind in the block parameter list, instead of using `el[0]` and `el[1]`:

```
h.sort_by {|key, value| value }
```

However, in this particular case, `el[1]` also happens to be identical to `el.last`, so that you could simply write

```
h.sort_by(&:last)
```

Comment: +1 for using a "keyed" sort rather than defining a comparison function when it isn't absolutely necessary.

Comment: @Karl Knechtel: Thanks! "Key" was the word I'm lookin for.

Comment: BTW, how does `{|k, v|...` know that it will actually be receiving **one** argument each time and that it should unpack it as a 2-tuple? Is it somehow inferred from the `h.sort_by` context? (To use the terminology you have in there: how does it know whether or not to perform a "destructuring bind"?) I don't really understand how the Ruby implementation of lambdas works on this level.

Comment: Hash mixes in Enumerable, which implements `sort` and `sort_by` using the collection's `each` method. Hash's `each` method produces [k,v] arrays, and the `|k,v|` in the block thus amounts to `k,v = [kx,vx]` parallel assignment. As Jörg's `|el|` example suggests, you can use a single variable there and get the behavior `el = [kx,vx]`. For that matter, you could do `|a,b,c,d,e|` and get `a,b,c,d,e = [kx,vx]`, although obviously that wouldn't be very useful.

Comment: @Karl Knechtel: It's probably easier to demonstrate: `def foo; yield 1; yield 1, 2; yield 1, 2, 3 end; puts '1 param'; foo {|a| p a }; puts '2 params'; foo {|a, b| p a, b }; puts '3 params'; foo {|a, b, c| p a, b, c }`. In short: block argument semantics are much less strict than method argument semantics. They behave more like multiple assignment. (In fact, prior to Ruby 1.9, blocks *did use* assignment, which meant that you do really crazy stuff like `foo {|@bar, baz.quux|}`, which would assign the value passed into the block to the instance variable `@bar` and call the setter `baz.quux=`.)

Comment: @Karl Knechtel: Sorry, I forgot the most interesting case for this question: the case where you `yield` an `Array`: `def foo; yield 1; yield 1, 2; yield 1, 2, 3; yield [1, 2] end; puts '1 param'; foo {|a| p a }; puts '2 params'; foo {|a, b| p a, b }; puts '3 params'; foo {|a, b, c| p a, b, c }`.

Comment: For the first example, h.sort_by {|k, v| [v, k] } is equivalent to h.sort_by {|k, v| v }, which more clearly shows you are sorting using the value.

Comment: how to sort in ascending by value and then descending by key?

Comment: I couldn't get the part that in very first code example `[v, k]` is an array of conditions, so for noobs - you can add more sort conditions if that suits you, for example `[v, k, v-k]`

Comment: @Darpan: Yes, arrays are lexicographically ordered. I think that is mentioned in the documentation. I used the term "element-wise", is that the problem? Should I replace it with "lexicographically"?

Comment: @JörgWMittag No no, I just did not get meaning of whole line 'This uses the fact that Array mixes in Comparable and defines <=> element-wise.', and using 'lexicographically' would make it even hard to comprehend :). It's good as it is.