# Sorting an array of dictionaries by their keys and values

Tags: algorithm, sorting

In my case, value has the priority, so I need to sort the array first by value, then alphabetically by key. Which algorithm/technique to use?

Here is an example:

```
[                           [
    d: 1,                       r: 0,
    z: 0,                       z: 0,
    r: 0,       =>              a: 1,
    a: 1,                       d: 1,
    e: 1                        e: 1
]                           ]
```

I was thinking of splitting the array in two groups (first group would me made of elements with value 0; second group of elements with value 1), sort each, then merge them again. But I am looking for a better solution.

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: And please provide your current code as well. Then we can look at it and find what is wrong.

Comment: Sorting functions usually take a comparison function as an argument. So all you need to do is implement a comparison between dictionaries.

Comment: @JosephCamacho Ruby, but I want to do it by hand.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Sorting a hash in ruby based on value and then key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4425333/sorting-a-hash-in-ruby-based-on-value-and-then-key)

Comment: @ggorlen No, because I want to do it by hand, without using Ruby's built-in functions :)

Comment: So, you basically want an algorithmatic approach?

Comment: I'm not really sure what "by hand" means, exactly. The algorithm is the same either way: turn the hash into an array of key-value pairs, then call the built in sort routine with a comparator. If you don't want to use the built in sort routine, then it sounds like the question is "how do I write quick/tim/merge sort by hand" which is going to be 99% of the work you'll need to do (writing the comparator is the same and trivial either way).

Comment: If for some reason you will not use a comparator, then the algorithm is "sort the values, then identify and iterate over each group of equivalent values and perform a sort on that subarray". Long story short.... `h.sort_by(&:reverse)`....

Comment: @ggorlen By hand means writing sorting algorithm myself. I guess I will go with comparator function route, but it a bit unclear at the moment for me how it fits into the regular sorting algorithm.

Comment: That's fine, but the problem is, if you edit your post to ask "how do I write a quick/tim/merge sort with a comparator", it's too broad and [off-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). You'll be referred to wikipedia and the question will be closed. So--head to wikipedia, pick a sorting algorithm you like and begin implementing it. Whichever sort you write will use `<` and `==` for ordering integers. All you do is add an additional parameter for a comparator block--use that in place of `<`. You're basically reinventing `sort_by`, which accepts such a block.